# How to apply QGraphicsOpacityEffect to some part of QGraphicsItem?

Tags: qt

How to apply QGraphicsBlurEffect to some part of QGraphicsItem.  Do I need to create customized QGraphicsBlurEffect ?

Comment: You could explain me better, your question can be interpreted in many ways. If you put an image that illustrates what you want it would be great

Comment: Yes. I think I can explain in better way. I have a custom QGraphicsItem which draws a filled rectangle. Why I am using custom QGraphicsItem is, I need to display some resizable points every corner of my item. So that user can drag and resize the item while clicking on the dots.   Finally I need to apply some blur effect to my item but not to the resizable corner dots. But when I apply QGraphicsBlurEffect, it effects to all drawing including resizable corner dots. How can I achive this ?